# VBA UserForm Find multiple records, display and cycle through

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm creating a userform where it searches for a unique ID on a sheet and displays the associated data located in the same row.

I've used the aid of another StackOverflow question but it's not working exactly for me

There are multiple datasets to the unique ID I'm searching for. The code I've got below, on clicking find, shows the first found record and pops up with a message box telling the user how many records are in the sheet. After clicking OK, the userform closes.

I want to edit it so after clicking OK, the user can click the FindNext button and the userform will show all the other records which match the original search.

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub FindNext_Click()
    Dim nextCell As Range
    Set nextCell = Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell)
    'FindNext loops round to the initial cell if it finds no other so we test for it
    If Not nextCell.Address(external:=True) = ActiveCell.Address(external:=True) Then
        updateFields anchorCell:=nextCell
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Find_Click()
    Worksheets("Master").Activate
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim rSearch As Range
    Set rSearch = Range("a1", Range("a65536").End(xlUp))
    Dim f      As Integer
    Dim c As Object

    strFind = Me.TextBox1.Value

    With rSearch
        Set c = .Find(strFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            updateFields anchorCell:=c
            FirstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                f = f + 1
               Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
            If f > 1 Then
                Select Case MsgBox("There are " & f & " instances of " & strFind, vbOKCancel Or vbExclamation Or vbDefaultButton1, "Multiple entries")

                    Case vbOK
                    Case vbCancel

                End Select
                Me.Height = frmMax

            End If
        Else: MsgBox strFind & " not listed"
        End If
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub updateFields(anchorCell As Range)
anchorCell.Select
With Me
    .TextBox2.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    .TextBox3.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    .TextBox4.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    .TextBox6.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
    .TextBox7.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 14).Value
    .TextBox8.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 15).Value
    .TextBox9.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 16).Value
    .TextBox10.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
    .TextBox11.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
    .TextBox12.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
    .TextBox13.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
    .TextBox14.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 21).Value
    .TextBox20.Value = anchorCell.Offset(0, 22).Value
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Without a bit more information it will be somewhat difficult to help you here. I can assume that the main issue is your `Select Case` statement since you're not doing anything when `OK` or `Cancel` is selected. If your datasets are on multiple sheets in the workbook you should just be able to enclose the `With` statement in a `For-Loop` to search across you datasets. Then you can say `Case vbCancel: Exit For`, otherwise continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for `FindNext_Click` uses the fact that the last row showed was set to be the current selection (see `anchorCell.Select` in `updateFields`). The problem is that in between these calls the user may have selected another cell or even another worksheet, a runtime error would occur.

I suggest another approach with only two functions, one that counts the matches and initiates the search, Another that is responsible of the updating and nexting"

```
Option Explicit
Private anchor As Range ' keeps track of the last shown row

Private Sub Find_Click()
    ' Only Displays the number of matches and delegates the updating to FidNext
    Dim count As Long
    count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Master").UsedRange.Columns("A"), TextBox1.Value)
    If count < 1 Then
        msgBox TextBox1.Value & " not listed"
        FindNext.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    FindNext.Enabled = True
    Set anchor = Worksheets("Master").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
    FindNext_Click ' Now delegate the work to FindNext
End Sub

Private Sub FindNext_Click()
'responsible of updating the userform and scrolling to the next field 
    Set anchor = Worksheets("Master").UsedRange.Columns("A").Find(TextBox1.Value, anchor)

    TextBox2.Value = anchor.offset(0, 2).Value
    TextBox3.Value = anchor.offset(0, 3).Value
    TextBox4.Value = anchor.offset(0, 4).Value
    TextBox6.Value = anchor.offset(0, 13).Value
    TextBox7.Value = anchor.offset(0, 14).Value
    TextBox8.Value = anchor.offset(0, 15).Value
    TextBox9.Value = anchor.offset(0, 16).Value
    TextBox10.Value = anchor.offset(0, 17).Value
    TextBox11.Value = anchor.offset(0, 18).Value
    TextBox12.Value = anchor.offset(0, 19).Value
    TextBox13.Value = anchor.offset(0, 20).Value
    TextBox14.Value = anchor.offset(0, 21).Value
    TextBox20.Value = anchor.offset(0, 22).Value

    Worksheets("Master").Activate
    anchor.EntireRow.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: For other users:

Just one edit; need to declare the strFind, i.e.,:

Dim strFind As string

Thanks, A.S.H!

Comment: @vinayman actually I dropped that variable. We have it already in `Textbox1.value`. (Answer Edited) `strFind` was only used in the message box anyway, no serious impact on the overall code.